# How can I disable auto set value in Symfony form?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, symfony-forms, symfony5

I create a form in controller:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
    ->add('test', TextType::class)
    ->add('submit', SubmitType::class)
    ->getForm();
```

and I have this code in my twig page:

```
{{ form(form, { 'attr': {'autocomplete': 'off'} }) }}
```

Now when I write a value for input (for example "123456") and when I submit the form and it's invalid, the page refreshes and my input value display "123456" and when I refresh page again value not change.

Comment: The first part (retaining values when validation fails) is something very sensible and I don't see why you would force the user to re-enter everything all over again just because validation failed. The second part (refreshing) is your browser caching the values.

Comment: @El_Vanja because my field is a verify code and when invalid code was change and last code not work

Comment: Ah, so something like a Captcha code that changes with every request?

Comment: @El_Vanja yes that is right

Comment: You could use PasswordType::class or create a custom field type that resets the value each time.

Comment: One way would be to manually reset the value in the model when handling the form submission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several ways to do it:

1. You can create a new form type and customise its rendering with a global form theme template
2. You can render the specific field differently
3. You can try to overwrite the `value` attribute while rendering the field (could not work on some form themes)

Read the [symfony documentation on form themes](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_themes.html) to know which solution is better for your use-case or application.

Anyway, for a validation code input (as read in the comments) I suggest to you to implement a new form type entirely and handle its rendering, options and logic separately.